# Listeners for JTextField text change

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, focuslistener

I have got a `JTextField` and I want to add listener to it, which will receive some event as soon as the `JTextField` looses focus (say when I press with mouse to another component). Also I want a listener to receive an event when the `text` parameter of `JTextField` is changed (like when I set `jtextfield.setText(anotherText)`). Any idea how should I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first one, you need a [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addFocusListener%28java.awt.event.FocusListener%29). For the second one, you need to add a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#addDocumentListener%28javax.swing.event.DocumentListener%29) to the [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument%28%29) of the text field.

Comment: You could also use a PropertyChangeListener if you're only interested in knowing when the text property changes

Comment: +1 and @MadProgrammer i make your comment an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

As @MadProgrammer point out, if you are only interested in listening `text` property. Just add a PropertyChangeListener.

Example:

```
   JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
   //for focus use FocusAdapter and just override focus lost
   textfield.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
       @Override
       public void focusLost(final FocusEvent evt){
           //i always like to wrap this method with swing utilities
           // which puts it at the end of the EventQueue, so it's executed after all pending events
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    //code here
                }
           });
       } 
  });

  textfield.addPropertyChangeListener("text", new PropertyChangeListener(){
             @Override
             public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt){
                    if(evt == null)
                        return;

                    if("text".equals(evt.getPropertyName())){
                         //code here
                    }
             }
  });
```

Comment: FYI the property change listener doesn't work for me, using Java 1.6.  It's never called.  Javadoc for java.asw.Container.addPropertyChangeListener lists the properties and does not include "text".  Perhaps it was added in a later version.

Comment: @JeffLearman,The "value" property might be the appropriate one to use.